Load data in new sheet using existing sheets in Excel using Vlookup or power query
I am working on an excel book which does have two sheets sheet1 and sheet2. This is a large data set consist of more than 20000 records. I could not get this figure out.
Sheet1 columns:
RecordID | Fullname
Sheet 2 columns:
Name | LegalName.
So I would like to create a new sheet with columns RecodID and VendorName.
In the New sheet VendorName field value is gonna be derived from sheet2 by comparing sheet1 Fullname field.
This my Condition:
If sheet1 "Fullname" field value is equal to Sheet2 "Name" field value then Sheet3's "VendorName" field value will be loaded with Sheet2's "Name" value
If sheet1 "Fullname" field value is not equal to  Sheet2 "Name" field value then check sheet1 "FullName" with Sheet2 "LegalName" field value, if equal then shee3's "vendorName" feild gonna be sheet2's LegalName value.
If neither matches then sheet3 "vendorName" field gonna be empty.
Essentially sheet3's values are gonna be derived from Sheet2 but after comparing it with FullName field in Sheet1. During the comparison case doesn't matter it should just match the text as is for equality. But when loading in sheet3 it should take exact value from sheet2 as is, no case manipulation or anything.

I do this often with power query and merge anti joins in either direction to show whats missing from each sheet. I'd look up a tutorial to load data and then look at power query merges.

It's not clear which version of Excel you are using, but if you have XLOOKUP, then try this formula - it assumes the data on Sheets 1 and 2 are formatted as tables named Table1 and Table2, respectively, but could easily be adapted to use other reference conventions:
=XLOOKUP(Table1[@Fullname],Table2[Name],Table2[LegalName],XLOOKUP(Table1[@Fullname],Table2[LegalName],Table2[LegalName],"",0),0)
The outer XLOOKUP tries to exact match the Fullname field from Table1 (Sheet 1) with the Name field from Table2 (Sheet 2). If it finds a match, it returns the LegalName field from Table2. If it doesn't find a match, then the inner XLOOKUP tries to exact match Fullname from Table1 with LegalName from Table2. If that matches, then it returns LegalName. If the inner XLOOKUP doesn't find a match, it returns a blank string.
